# Show Hide Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have added Sherlock action bar to an activity by using the following line in manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"
```

I want to save on screen space and hide the action bar by default and show it only when user taps on the screen. I have seen it in Aldiko app but don't know how to implement it.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: for interest you might want to look into the Full Screen app template that you can get when you choose to start a New Application in Eclipse. There is some nice code for auto-hiding the action bar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To hide use below code on your activity `onCreate()` method,

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

To show use below code on tap event,

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Follow [ActionBarSherlock Usage](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Working very fine. I just now came to know that the Sherlock ActionBar has same API methods as Google's ActionBar. Thanks once again

Comment: Worked for me too, but... how to hide only, for example, the shareprovider?

Answer (score 1):

First give the id to your wrapping node of activity layout (main_layout.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/containerMain"
```

Second implement this in your code for activity:

```
boolean isActionBarShow=true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    a=getSupportActionBar();
    RelativeLayout rl= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.containerMain);
    rl.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if (isActionBarShow)
                {
                    a.hide();
                    isActionBarShow=false;                      
                }
                else
                {
                    a.show();
                    isActionBarShow=true;

                }
            return false;
        }
    });
```